# div not showing correctly using bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display some divs on the same row but I have no ideea why I can't. When I have 2 rows the div containing the button is in the correct position. But when i have only one row the button will be on the second row.
Here is what i get:
[image]

and here is what i want:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row" >
  <div  *ngFor="let field of fields " class="spacing ">
    <div class="display col ">
    <p>Field name: {{field.name}}</p>
    <p>Crop Type: {{field.Crop}}</p>
    <p>Description: {{field.Description}}</p>
    <button >Modify</button>
    <button >View all</button>
  </div>
    </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
  <button class="center" onclick="document.getElementById('frame').style.display = 'block'">Create new field</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
button{
  background-color: #1976d2;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
  
}
.display{
border: 5px solid #1976d2;
padding: 45px;
box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
border-radius: 15px;
margin-top:20px;
left: 5%;

    
}
.spacing{
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.center{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

How can i make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to use columns in bootstrap is being direct children from the row element, so the element with the "spacing" class should be a col class:

```
<div  *ngFor="let field of fields " class="col-sm-10">
.
.
.
</div>
```